# Leave ports open in WPF application and then read as needed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that reads data from COM ports every few minutes. It is my understanding that if you're reading data constantly from COM ports it's better to leave them open instead of opening and closing every time. I need some help doing this.

I've tried setting and opening the port in the OnStartup method of Application and then stick a DataReceived method to it but that doesn't seem to work when I'm on a different page in the window. The method isn't called. I tried passing the COM port instance to the other page through application.current.resources and tried reading from it but that results in an exception as well.

Is there any standard way of opening ports when the application starts and attaching global event handlers to them that will trigger from anywhere in the application. If I can make that happen, I can then store the data read in application resources and use it throughout the application. Any hints would be appreciated.

Raza

Comment: Are you using MVVM or writing everything i code behind? Using MVVM would allow you to handle the COM port like you would in any other .net application, and just signal the view when data is read.

Comment: Could you not create a class with an OnRead<Data> event in another thread, and simply Invoke your main WPF window when data is received?

Comment: Fishy could you expand a little bit? I'm aware of MVVM but I can't quite figure out how to add global event handlers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really go into the detail required to show you how you set up a complete MVVM model. I would suggest you check out some basic tutorials on MVVM and databindings and maybe look into an MVVM framework, like Caliburn.Micro. If you develop a lot using WPF, or intend to do so, it is well invested time :) Best of luck!

Comment: I didn't ask for details. I know how MVVM works. In a nutshell you bind you viewmodel to an element in the view and then have it inherit from a baseviewmodel which implements inotifypropertychanged so that the UI updates when a public field in your VM changes. I still don't see how this would benefit my situation.

Answer (score 0):

When using com object the DataReceived Event of the object not always triggered correct.

This is why even on the MSDN example of using com port they use Thread.

because you didn't gave any code, here is how you read and write using com ports in .net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

If you need something more specific please supply more details.